# android how to reduce view thickness

Tags: android

My code is shown below. My view is displayed with so much thickness; I hope to reduce this.

[image: http://imgur.com/KaIpJee]

I wish to add a separator like in this image:

[image: http://imgur.com/2ZtcoIB]

How do I make a small vertical view?

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#C0C0C0"
 android:layout_weight="2"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TableLayout
         android:id="@+id/table"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"




android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

     <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="left"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Farm a School" />
    <View
android:layout_width="0.1dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
/>


    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Take a survey" />
    <View
android:layout_width="0.1dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
  />
     <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Share this App" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your black separator views, first make the view width 1px and not 0.1dp and also play with android:maxWidth / android:minWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get rid of `stretchcolumns` the * will mean that every column will be stretching to fill the screen. Resulting in the bar ignoring your widths set.

If you still want the widths of the text to share screen space. Use

```
 android:stretchColumns="0,2,4"
```

Where the 0,2,4 are each of your columns index that contain text.

Comment: how i set? help me how i make small vertical view?

Comment: See the edit, you can replace your stretchcolumns with the one above and it should work.